# Altering $PATH on OSX won't apply the changes

Tags: php, macos, laravel, path, terminal

I'm trying to use Laravel. It seems to come with a handy command `laravel` to create new projects and do other stuff. One of the laracasts I'm following tells me to alter the $PATH and add `~/.composer/vendor/bin/` to it, so all applications in that folder can be executed without typing in the full path.

I've noticed there was no .bash_profile-file on my MacBook, so I created on following this tutorial: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/add-shell-path-osx/

When I reopen the file, my changes are there. The content of the file is 1 line: `export PATH="~/.composer/vendor/bin/:$PATH"`.

But when typing `echo $PATH` using Terminal the output is:

```
MacBook-Pro-van-Ben:~ BenFransen$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I assume maybe the .bash_profile-file needs to be linked to Terminal? I;m completely new to these kind of things.. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! I had to restart Terminal in order to make the changes apply. Silly question, but I will leave this here in case anyone else stumbles upon this issue.